# Exclude lines by pattern in sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying write a sed command in bash that updates all references to javascript and css files in an HTML file with $(name).min.js, however I want to ignore files with the word MANAGER_WIDGET in the path e.g.

Replace:

`&lt;script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/scripts.js"/&gt;`

But not:

```
`&lt;script type="text/javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/Plugin.js"/&gt;`
```

So far I've got the following sed command which adds .min to all files js and css files:

```
sed "s/\.\([jscss]\+\)\"/\.min\.\1\"/g" index.html
```

It would be great if someone can show me how I can also exclude lines with MANAGER_WIDGET in them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sed '/MANAGER_WIDGET/!s/\.\([jscss]\+\)\"/\.min\.\1\"/g' index.html
```